# Как отключить подсказку корректного текста в UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Я использую UITextView для показа текста в ячейке таблицы.

По нажатию на ячейку(по textView) я открываю экран для редактирования текста переопределив метод делегата(UITextViewDelegate) textViewDidBeginEditing(установив туда свой хэндлер).

Если слово было введено не корректно, то по нажатию на это слово выскакивает подсказка с корректным словом. Предположу что это UIMenuController(99%), но в иерархии не видно это меню.
Мало того что подсказка выскакивает, так еще и с задержкой, что приводит к тому что она оказывается уже поверх открытого нового экрана для редактирования текста.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    selectHandler?()
}
```

1) textView.isSelectable - мне не подходит, так как потом не работает textViewDidBeginEditing.

2) textView.isEditable - также не подходит.

3) с canPerformAction - ничего не получается(я перепробовал кучу различных способов).
Допустим код ниже.

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Или допустим это.

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ||
        action == #selector(replace(_:withText:)) ||
        action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleBoldface(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleItalics(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleUnderline(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.increaseSize(_:)) ||
    action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.decreaseSize(_:))

   {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

4) textView.autocorrectionType = .no - не для этого, не по моей проблеме.

5) Такой способ тоже не подойдет, смотрите код ниже.

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

6) UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = false - это не срабатывало в разных способах.

7) textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false - мне точно не подходит.

Выделение с некорректного текста красным маркером(помимо этой всплывающей подсказки), которое тоже нужно было не показывать, я смог убрать с помощью этого кода ниже.

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let selectedRange: UITextRange? = textView.selectedTextRange
    var selectedText: String? = nil
    if let selectedRange = selectedRange {
        selectedText = textView.text(in: selectedRange)
    }
    if (selectedText?.count ?? 0) > 1 && (selectedText?.count ?? 0) <= textView.text.count {
        textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
    }
}
```

Вопрос: есть идеи? подскажите их пожалуйста.

[image: скрин1]

[image: скрин2]

Comment: не совсем понятна логика, то есть у вас в ячейке таблицы текст редактируемый и при этом вы при тапе на него открываете отдельный экран для редактирования снова того же текста?

Comment: @schmidt9 все верно.
по задумке дизайнера теперь именно так все и происходит.

чуть ранее я использовал простой лейбл для отображения текста в ячейке.

Comment: `textView.autocorrectionType = .no` почему не подходит?

Comment: @schmidt9 у меня нет конкретных предположений, но в awakeFromNib я устанавливаю это свойство.

есть только догадка, что эпл разделяет одно с другим.

Comment: @schmidt9

из описания флага autocorrectionType:

This property determines whether autocorrection is enabled or disabled during typing. With autocorrection enabled, the text object tracks unknown words and suggests a more suitable replacement candidate to the user, replacing the typed text automatically unless the user explicitly overrides the action.
The default value for this property is UITextAutocorrectionType.default, which for most input methods results in autocorrection being enabled.

Comment: @schmidt9 и тут не говорится ничего о том что подсказка перестанет показываться, видимо только сама автокоррекция отключается и все на этом

Comment: Однако она перестает показываться при установке этого свойства `no`

Comment: @schmidt9 если вы проверяете, то вы на слово жмете?

Comment: да, `autocorrectionType = .no` убирает всплывающую подсказку с исправлением, другое дело, что это не убирает меню к командами, если вас это тоже заботит

Comment: @schmidt9 однако у меня проблема осталась. как я писал выше, этот флаг у меня установлен.
нет, остальные меню меня не заботят.

Comment: `textView.isSelectable - мне не подходит, так как потом не работает textViewDidBeginEditing` - как вариант назначить свой tap recognizer

Comment: @schmidt9 спасибо, разобрался, ответ написал ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

**Шаг 1(делаем кастомный класс для UITextView):**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    var selectHandler: (() -> Void)?

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let _ = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            return true
        }
        selectHandler?()
        return false
    }
}
```

**Шаг 2(назначаем свое действие для selectHandler в самой ячейке):**

```
textView.selectHandler = selectHandler(Твой метод, который хочешь вызывать)
```

**Не забываем установить новый класс для аутлета textView(CustomTextView).**

**В том числе и для ксибины.**